# Promises getting resolved twice in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I am learning to use angularjs with requirejs and angular-ui-router. I created a plunker over here http://plnkr.co/edit/iA8zVQWP3ypRFiZeRDzY?

```
<div ui-view ></div>

<script data-main="require-config" src="http://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.1.20/r.js"></script>
```

The startup file index.html has a reference to require-config.js which loads the required third-party javascript libraries, resolves dependencies and bootstraps my module which is in app.js

```
angular.element().ready(function() {
      //bootstrap the app manually
      angular.bootstrap(document,['myApp']);
    });
```

I am using ui.router to resolve appropriate states and navigate to the appropriate page

```
define(['angular', 'story'
], function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'myApp.story'])
    .controller('TabController', ['$scope', '$state', function($scope, $state) {
        $scope.tabs = [
            {route: 'main.story', label : "Promises", active : false},
            //more routes here.
        ];

        $scope.go = function(route){
            $state.go(route);
        };

        $scope.active = function(route){
            return $state.is(route);
        };

        $scope.$on("$stateChangeSuccess", function() {
            $scope.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
                tab.active = $scope.active(tab.route);
            });
        });

    }])
```

$stateProvider will route to appropriate state.

```
config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state('main', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/main',
        templateUrl:  'tabs.html',
          controller: 'TabController'
        })        
        .state('main.story', {
        url: '/story',
        templateUrl:  'story.html',
          controller: 'storyController'
        })
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/main/story');
  }])
```

and ui.bootstrap to use tabs provided by bootstrap library.

```
<tabset>
        <tab
            ng-repeat="t in tabs"
            heading="{{t.label}}"
            select="go(t.route)"
            active="t.active">
        </tab>
    </tabset>
```

This plunker is working with bugs. When I look at the Network in Chrome, the json files ( chapter-1.json and chapter-2.json ) are getting loaded/resolved twice.

I also verified the code without using requireJS and it is working (loading scripts using script tag manually) fine. The promises are getting resolved only once. So, there is some configuration that I am doing incorrectly while using requirejs.

I also verified the files getting loaded twice using $httpProvider.interceptors as well.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In app.js, you are indicating `storyController` as the controller for your `main.story` state, but you have an `ng-controller="storyController"` inside your story.html.

The result is that you are initializing two `storyController`s and each one calls `.getText()` once.

You can solve this by removing the `ng-controller` from your story.html:

```
<body>
  <div>
    {{chapter1}}<br>
    {{chapter2}}
  </div>
</body>
```